Text in source code not appearing in pdf
Good day,
I am a very new user of LaTeX, working in Overleaf. A problem has arisen in a document I'm working on.
There is a block of text that cannot be separated by a pagebreak, so I've put it all in a minipage. I've done this several times already in the document, with no problems. But for some reason, when I press 'recompile', this block of text comes out as two blank lines.
This is happening with subsequent blocks in the same format.
The problem seems to be with lines 162--169 (see inserted screenshot).

I get the following error message:
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
Latex error: \begin {minipage} on input line 162 ended by \end{list}
Missing } inserted
Underfull \hbox{badness 2521} in paragraph at lines 169-169
Underfull \hbox{badness 10000} in paragraph at lines 169-169

None of this seems to correspond to anything in my source code. I've searched for extra braces, and for things like "\end{list}", but they are not there.
I would gratefully appreciate some help with this, if anyone can spot the problem.
Thank you, and merry festive season!
Andrew

It's impossible to diagnose, unless you show a complete example of code that we can play with. Likely, the problem is in \ex, but without knowing what it does…

If I remove '\ex.', the text appears. \ex. is part of the linguex package. It numbers examples sequentially from the beginning of the document.

Unrelated but do not end paragraphs with \\ .

Your overleaf display shows 15 errors, after any error any pdf is not expected to be usable fix each error one at a time starting with the first. If you wantvhelp you need to provide an example and the log as text in a code block not as a screen image

You need an empty line before the \end{minipage}.

Thanks, Ulrike, that worked!

yes, but remove the unnecessary \\ , then you will get less orange warnings.

Okay, I will do that.
